# Sitefinity module recursive content type relationships

Tags: content-management-system, relationship, content-type, sitefinity

I have a question for any SiteFinity experts out there. I'm coming from an umbraco background and have started developing a SiteFinity module to create a data container with relationships between entities.

There's an example of an online travel agency site on the Telerik YouTube channel. They build a module with the following content hierarchy;

```
Countries -> Cities -> Hotels
                    -> Restaurants
                    -> Airports
                    -> Festivals
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCfc9GQoGoQ&feature=youtu.be

This all makes perfect sense if festivals were always located in a city. But what about the scenario where the festival is national? Would I have to implement the same content type of 'Festivals' against both 'Cities' and 'Countries' in order to accomplish this or is there a way to have 'Festivals' sit at the root of the hierarchy and allow me to selected a related 'Country' or 'City' as they are required?

Thanks,
Brian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to make Festivals its own type(DynamicModule).  Then you can use related content and relate a festival to a Country or City or Both. This is assuming you you are using Sitefinity 7.xx

Comment: Thanks Jon, I've now investigated this approach more and can see that it looks like the correct way to achieve this. Would you mind answering one more question for me? The last piece of the puzzle for me is that in Umbraco every page created is associated with a content type. I can therefore ask for all pages of content type 'Festival' to then iterate over each festival page and it's fields. I can't see in SiteFinity how to associate a page with the data from a custom module other than checking whether the page has specific widgets placed upon it. What's the correct way to find all festivals?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow your question. But to query festivals you can use the code examples that sitefinity provides in the module builder. Something like DynamicModuleManager.GetManager().GetDataItems(type);